# Paypal Classic SOAP API down?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

We use the old SOAP paypal API, and have been for almost a year, and every transaction since July 10th has failed.  Is api.paypal.com down?  We made zero code changes.  The sandbox account fails too.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any outages at the time. Are you still having issues?

New certificates were released for the Sandbox and Live environments: 
https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/952

That may help you out depending on the error you're getting.

Comment: Yes, I am still having issues.  Connections to https://api.paypal.com/2.0/ hang indefinitely.  Connections to https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/ immediately disconnect. It is not a problem just with the server either, I cannot get a response https://api.paypal.com/2.0/ from any computer.

Comment: Please note that we are using the certificate endpoint, not the signature endpoint (https://api-3t.paypal.com/2.0/).  The signature endpoint appears to be alive and well.

Comment: Have you tried using the new SSL certificates I provided? It doesn't matter if you're using the certificate or signature method you'll still need to use the updated certificates.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and what I did was change my API URLs from:

https://api.paypal.com/2.0/ 
and

https://api-aa.paypal.com/2.0/

To:

https://api-3t.paypal.com/2.0/ 
and

https://api-aa-3t.paypal.com/2.0/